# id token cannot be verified in g+ api

Tags: java, api, jsp, google-app-engine, oauth

Hello any one can help me?

> public static GoogleIdToken.Payload getPayload (String tokenString)
>   throws Exception {
>
> ```
>     JacksonFactory jacksonFactory = new JacksonFactory();
>     GoogleIdTokenVerifier googleIdTokenVerifier =
>                         new GoogleIdTokenVerifier(new NetHttpTransport(),jacksonFactory);
>
>     GoogleIdToken token = GoogleIdToken.parse(jacksonFactory, tokenString);
>     System.out.println(token);
>     if (googleIdTokenVerifier.verify(token)) {
>
>         GoogleIdToken.Payload payload = token.getPayload();
>         if (!GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID.equals(payload.getAudience())) {
>             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Audience mismatch");
>         } else if (!GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID.equals(payload.getAuthorizedParty())) {
>             throw new IllegalArgumentException("Client ID mismatch");
>         }
>         return payload;
>     } else {
>         throw new IllegalArgumentException("id token cannot be verified");
>     }
> }
> ```

GoogleIdTokenVerifier.verify() method was returned false.but token is their.
pleas help me.................................

Comment: What is the result of `System.out.println(token);`?

Comment: Which API are you using? Is it the Google+ API or the Google App Engine API? Could you also explain what your code is doing and where it is getting the tokenString ?